# How to generate a MAC value using OpenSSL on Command?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, command

I'm a new for OpenSSL library. Now, I want to compute MAC value of a file using OpenSSL by command line.

I have known how to get helps and generate a Hash value:

1.Get helps:

```
openssl md5 -help
Usage: md5 [options] [file...]

General options:
 -help               Display this summary
 -list               List digests
 -engine val         Use engine e, possibly a hardware device
 -engine_impl        Also use engine given by -engine for digest operations
 -passin val         Input file pass phrase source

Output options:
 -c                  Print the digest with separating colons
 -r                  Print the digest in coreutils format
 -out outfile        Output to filename rather than stdout
 -keyform format     Key file format (PEM or ENGINE)
 -hex                Print as hex dump
 -binary             Print in binary form
 -d                  Print debug info
 -debug              Print debug info

Signing options:
 -sign val           Sign digest using private key
 -verify val         Verify a signature using public key
 -prverify val       Verify a signature using private key
 -sigopt val         Signature parameter in n:v form
 -signature infile   File with signature to verify
 -hmac val           Create hashed MAC with key
 -mac val            Create MAC (not necessarily HMAC)
 -macopt val         MAC algorithm parameters in n:v form or key
 -*                  Any supported digest
 -fips-fingerprint   Compute HMAC with the key used in OpenSSL-FIPS fingerprint

Random state options:
 -rand val           Load the file(s) into the random number generator
 -writerand outfile  Write random data to the specified file

Provider options:
 -provider_path val  Provider load path (must be before 'provider' argument if required)
 -provider val       Provider to load (can be specified multiple times)

Parameters:
 file                Files to digest (optional; default is stdin)
```

2.Generate a Hash value of MD5 and SHA1:

```
$ openssl md5 examples.desktop
MD5(examples.desktop)= 189e725f4587b679740f0f7783745056

$ openssl sha1 examples.desktop
SHA1(examples.desktop)= a64e9fede92c55932ce82d77891f77a1f015a9f1
```

Now, How can I obtain helps，generate MAC value and input a key for it?

Comment: use the `hmac` or `mac` option.

Comment: ```HMAC``` is a specific message authentication code algorithm. You can use ```hmac``` to show me how it works.